# Can Access-Control-Request-Headers be disabled in Axios?

Tags: ajax, axios, cors

I am wondering if this header is added by Axios or if it is added by the browser... to see if I can disable it in the client or must add support for it in the server.

I added a custom token `x-access-token` and I'm having CORS issues.

Comment: That's a request header, it's set by the client to tell the server during the preflight what headers it can expect on the actual request: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Request-Headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to Jon's comment: The `Access-Control-Request-Headers` header is added by the *browser*: When the client application desires to make a request (via [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch) or [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)) that includes a "non-standard" header like `x-access-token`, the browser first makes a preflight request with a header like `Access-Control-Request-Headers: x-access-token`, and only if the preflight response contains [`Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-access-token`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers) will it make the desired request.

It is your server's duty to produce the correct preflight response.